# Renewal not recording activity

Tags: civimember, activities

I'm doing some testing on a CiviContribute page in preparation for implementing CiviMember.

During the course of testing, it seems that renewals aren't creating activity records.

Is there some kind of date differential requirement before it logs?

My current testing involved creating a new membership, but also renewing the same day. This initial "renewal" was also an upsell. I then renewed that using the same level.

I also got the same result when testing a renewal without an upsell.

I'm running Drupal 7.37 with CiviCRM 4.6.3. No extensions are installed.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: To give a good answer, we'll need a little bit more information.  Could you please post your CiviCRM version number, which CMS software you're using with version number (e.g. Wordpress 4.2.2, Drupal 7.37), and whether you have any CiviCRM extensions installed?

Comment: Jon, thanks for responding. I should have known better as a software tester. I'm running Drupal 7.37 with CiviCRM 4.6.3. No extensions are installed. The initial "renewal" was also an upsell. I then renewed that using the same level. I also got the same result when testing a renewal without an upsell.

Comment: Is your renewal form a Civi contribution page or a Drupal webform? I don't think the former is configurable, but I know the latter gives you a lot of control over if and how the activity is created.

Comment: CiviContribute page.

Comment: I have just edited the question to include the information provide in the comments by @jgillmanjr.  Coleman and Jon G weren't asking for info already given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue to be as a result of CiviCRM seeing the payment as being a test.

Essentially, I used the PayPal sandbox configuration for the "production" processor. Looking back at the contributions for the membership, it stated the type was 'Member Dues (test)'.

After setting up and using the dummy processor, the contribution stated was just 'Member Dues', and it then recorded the contribution and membership renewal activities.